# viper.AutomaticEnv() gets environment variable doesn't work properly

Tags: go, viper-go

I was trying to isolate the development config file from production config by setting a environment variable. Operating System: `MAC OS`, I set a environment variable `DEBUG = true` through `.bash_profile` by adding `export DEBUG = True`. `echo $debug` gets correct value `true`. I wrote a function using `viper` which fetches the value of "debug". But print nil. Where part is wrong?

```
func GetEnvInfo(env string) string {
    viper.AutomaticEnv()
    v := viper.Get(env)
    return v
}

func main() {
    env := GetEnvInfo("debug")
    fmt.Println(env)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

viper only looks for environment variables matching parameters that you've already told it about. For example, if you say `viper.SetDefault("debug", true)` before you call viper.AutomaticEnv(), it should then pick up the `$debug` environment variable as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

if you use vscode, you should add env in launch.json.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "${fileDirname}",
        "env": {"DEBUG": "true"},
        "args": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because environment variables are case-sensitive. This is a quote form the [viper readme](https://github.com/spf13/viper#working-with-environment-variables):

> When working with ENV variables, it’s important to recognize that Viper treats ENV variables as case sensitive.

Since you set `DEBUG` and read `debug` this is expected. I don't understand why bash does returns true for `echo $debug` since bash is also supposed to be case-sensitive.